# ASP.Net MVC Webgrid custom pager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I just started using webgrid helper ,seem to be good, but having issue in creating pager. I want to create a pager on top and bottom of grid.

pager format is |dropdown| |previous button| |text|1-10 of 230 rows|text| |Nextbutton|

if i change dropdown number of rows shud change per selection . any thoughts how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not supported at the moment by the WebGrid helper. The pager only supports FirstLast, NextPrevious, Numeric and any combination of those. A dropdown is not supported.